# How can I improve this question to be more concise and on-topic for this site?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm new to this site, and to the subject of computer science. Since I don't fully understand the question I'm interested in asking, and I don't want to ask a bad question, I'd like to know how I can improve this question in a way that will make it acceptable for the site.

Maybe I'm asking this in a way that doesn't fully make sense out of ignorance with the topic. Any tips on the right question to ask, or the right way to ask it would be helpful. I'm savvy with computers, but not at all with hardware engineering, and I'd like to learn to interpret diagrams like this so that I can better educate myself on the ALU and similar components.

*Here's the question that I'd like to ask:*

### How do I interpret this diagram of and adder-subtractor?

Stepping foot past the realm of software, out of want for an understanding of the advanced fundamentals of hardware, I've found myself looking at a diagram of an adder-subtractor that I don't know how to interpret.

[image]

This is a supporting diagram in [Wikipedia's documentation on an adder-subtractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder%E2%80%93subtractor), accompanied by the description:

> A 4-bit ripple-carry adder–subtractor based on a 4-bit adder that
>   performs one's complement on A when D=1 to yield S=B-A

I would like to begin educating myself on bare-bones hardware structure and logic at this level, however I do this out of interest in obtaining a fuller understanding as a software engineer, but not in becoming an actual hardware engineer.

So, without taking on a hardware engineer's reading list, I'd like to know in the least possible detail (simplest way):

- What is this representing exactly, in terms of hardware? Am I seeing the pathway of electric current through a chip on a logic board? Exactly what physical components are represented in this diagram?
- I assume the arrows represent a current. I also notice that there are some green arrows connected to small dots, as well as some orange pieces with a 1 & 0, and blue pieces labeled "1-bit Full Adder". What do each of these four components of the diagram mean?
- Finally, I see that the arrow's path seems to start at D. What does D represent? Are the next arrow points simply paths that a current can take to complete the operation?

Comment: Why this question? Just ask and let community moderation take care of the rest.

Comment: I think it's acceptable to "ask before asking" - that keeps question quality up in the cases where new users aren't sure of what is and isn't on topic. Am I wrong? Also, often on SE sites, when a new user posts something off topic, he sort of gets his head chopped off for it. Down-votes, negative comments, etc. I'd like to avoid the possibility.

Comment: I notice that traffic seems to be pretty slow on this site. Is it doing badly with beta?

Comment: Given that you have never participated on this site before, I think both your questions can be answered by being an active member for a few weeks. (Of course, posting stuff "we" don't like will lead to downvotes and close votes. That's not a bad thing, though; it's how it works. By posting here first, you create additional work.) Regarding traffic, I don't with which sites you are comparing. [SO] and the other big ones are clearly in other leagues, but we have a quite high question/day value. Cf [stackexchange.com/sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: @Raphael It was my understanding, based on the tips given when asking a question, that it's acceptable to ask about whether or not a question is on topic before putting it to the real site, thus possibly generating bad content.

Comment: Well, if you insist, I recommend [chat].

Comment: @Raphael thanks man!